# Linear Algebra > Pablos Problem via Simplex Method

Tags: linear-algebra, simplex-method

In Pablos problem via Simplex method :

> The Conundrum City school board is heavily influenced by the local fruit grower's association. They have stipulated that children eat at least $7$ oranges and $5$ apples per week. Parents and teachers have agreed that eating at least $15$ pieces of fruit per week is a good thing, but school janitors argue that too much fruit makes a terrible mess, so that children should eat no more than $25$ pieces of fruit per week.
>
> $$s = 5x + 10y$$
>
> This linear function of $f(x, y)$ represents the grams of sugar in $x$ apples and $y$ oranges.

The problem is asking us to minimize s subject to the four linear inequalities listed above.
$$x\ge 5$$
$$y\ge 7$$
$$x + y \le 25$$

$$\implies15 \leq x + y \leq 25 $$

But in Simplex method, all variables are to obey the non-negativity $x_i \geq 0$ constraint.

So let’s select $x_1=x-5$ and $x_2=y-7$; Hence,

$\implies 15 \leq (x1+x2)+12 \leq 25$

$\implies 3 \leq (x1+x2) \leq 13$

Since these equations have inequalities $\leq, \geq $ and hence **NOT** of the form $Mx = v$ where $M$ is some Matrix of coefficients.

We introduce *slack variables* $x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_4 \geq 4$.

***QUESTION:*** I don’t understand why $x_4 \geq 4$ How `4`?

$ \implies c_1:= x_1 + x_2 -x_3 = 3\ \ \ , \ \ \ \ c2:= x_1 + x_2 + x_4 = 13$

The matrix form looks like:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
13\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We also want to  **minimize** sugar: $s = 5x + 10y$, but the STANDARD form of the simplex method **maximizes**, hence:

*objective function f* = $-s + (5*5 + 7*10) = -5x_1 - 10x_2 + 95$

Note: Notice that it makes no difference whether we maximize $-s$ or $-s + 95$, we choose the latter since it is a linear function of $(x_1, x_2)$

$5x_1 + 10x_2 + f =0$:

$$ 
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & f
\end{array}\right]
$$

$$\implies
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 13 \\
    \hline
    5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

here, it seems simplex algo already terminated as last row has (`+`) coefficients $\implies x_1=0=x_2$ would be optimal. **However**,this does not solve constraints for positive values of *slack variables* {$x_3, x_4$}. So we need to add *artificial variables* {$x_5, x_6$}. Such that:

$$c_1 \rightarrow c_1 - x5\ \ , \ \ \ \ c_2 \rightarrow c_2 - x6$$

The above is done so that for a large positive $\alpha$ the *objective function* $f$ is only maximal when the *artificial variables* disappear = 0. Where $f - \alpha x_5 - \alpha x_6$. Taking $\alpha = 10$ we get:
$$ 
\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc|c}
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & f
\end{array}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
    1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 13 \\
    \hline
    5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 1 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

After a series of `ERO`s:

$$R'_3 = R_3 + 15R_1$$

$$R'_2 = R_3 + 15R_1$$

$$R'_3 = R_3 + 10R_2$$

We arrive at:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
    \hline
    0 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 5 & 10 & 1 & -15
  \end{array}\right]
$$

The solution in the book says {$x_2, x_3, x_5, x_6$} have zero coefficients? But looking at the matrix above I do not see zero as a coefficient for $x_2$; rest are slack and artificial, so can it assumed to be zero? Not sure about any of this, please help understand this step.

Here is a screenshot of this section in the book, and my edits of my interpretation of these steps:

[image: link thats a screeshot to the page with steps]

Comment: Please do not omit essential information from the post, only to keep it in a link. Any info that a user would need to answer properly (like the full problem statement and your previous work) should be typed out inside the post.

Comment: Was quoting the original book page hence used the image. Thanks to your recommendation ive updated and typed it out best I could.